# battle.net crashes every time i try to log in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine, crash, winetricks

I'm on a 20.04 LTS fresh install and I can't log into [battle.net](https://battle.net). The login screen pops up, I enter my info to log in, and it crashes every time. I'm on the most recent update.

I've already looked around on the internet and forums and tried the basic fixes people used, especially from these forums, and nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a [tutorial here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-battle-net-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux-desktop), which might give some info about "Winetricks" settings needed.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of the battle.net client does not like normal WINE.

It does however, seem to work fine in proton, using the latest Glorious Eggroll release.

You can use Lutris to leverage Glorious Eggroll, and it will work just fine. See this Reddit thread:

https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/kb92nr/heres_how_you_can_use_proton_with_the_latest/

I have successfully installed, updated, and played games with the Battle.net client this way.